# Custom font not loading in Rails

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, fonts

I have a Rails 4.1.8 app where I am trying to use custom avenir fonts.
I have added the fonts in 2 places app/assets/fonts & app/assets/stylesheets. I also have added some of these in vendor/assets/stylesheets/fonts.
One of the fonts AvenirLTStd-Heavy.otf is not getting applied somehow.

```
screen.scss

@font-face {
  font-family: "AvenirLTStd-Heavy";
  src: url('/assets/fonts/AvenirLTStd-Heavy.otf');
}

.avenir-heavy {
  font-family: "AvenirLTStd-Heavy";
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

application.rb

config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join(* %w(vendor assets bower_components))
config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join('app', 'assets', 'fonts')
config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join('vendor', 'assets', 'stylesheets', 'fonts')    
config.assets.precompile += %w( .svg .eot .woff .ttf .otf)

config/initializers/assets.rb

Rails.application.config.assets.paths << "#{Rails.root}/app/assets/fonts"
Rails.application.config.assets.paths << "#{Rails.root}/vendor/assets/stylesheets/fonts"
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( .svg .eot .woff .ttf .otf)
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: how about this `/assets/AvenirLTStd-Heavy.otf` ?

Comment: Tried. Didn't work.

Comment: oh sorry, if you are using `.scss` file, try `asset-url('AvenirLTStd-Heavy.otf')`, and don't forget to add extention file on `config/initialize/assets.rb`

Comment: I have updated my question. Please check.

Answer (score 0):

Include your font path in assets precompile paths and just use the font name & specify the format as below:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "AvenirLTStd-Heavy";
  src: url('AvenirLTStd-Heavy.otf') format("opentype");
}
```